# Can't view anything in org-agenda: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 2

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Whenever I try to view my org-agenda, I get a blank buffer with "Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 2" in the minibuffer. I've followed dozens of tutorials and bug reports and nothing applies. Can anyone help me?

I'm using Emacs 26.2, with Spacemacs 0.200.13.x, with no org preferences in my .emacs or .spacemacs files. The issue is only present when running as Spacemacs, with plain Emacs it works fine.

I launch agenda with `M-x org-agenda-file-to-front`, then `M-x org-agenda a`. It launches an agenda buffer that begins populating, but errors as soon as it hits an actual TODO item.

Comment: Could you please specify how you start the agenda, and whatever org-agenda related preference you have in your `.emacs` please.

Comment: @manandearth My apologies, the question has been updated.

Comment: Does `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` get you a backtrace for the error?  If so, add it to the question.

Comment: @phils It did, but I found out the issue (forgot to post here, my bad). I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the org layer to Spacemacs solved the issue, things work just fine now.

Comment: The answer doesn't explain things. Please explain how you discovered the solution - show the backtrace. Say how you added "the org layer" to Spacemacs, and why that "solved the issue".

Comment: @Drew Needlessly hostile. There was no relevant backtrace I could find, and I added the org layer to Spacemacs the way you add any layer, adding to the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` list

Comment: Please consider mentioning in the answer that you added the "org layer" by adding it to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` list. And showing the code for that would help readers.

Comment: @enki: Needlessly defensive. You should consider Drew's comment as guidance for how to write a good answer, not as hostile action. I started out the same way as you: with one-sentence answers that assumed that the reader was ... me. I learnt, with Drew's guidance, to write more complete, self-contained answers that can be understood (with some effort perhaps) by people who are just embarking on their emacs journey. Such answers have a better chance to be useful to more people in the future.

Comment: Here is an example of what I meant: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70211/org-agenda-not-displaying-agendaorg-agenda-skip-wrong-number-of-arguments-0