# org-agenda not displaying agenda`org-agenda-skip: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 1), 2`

Tags: org-agenda, org-journal

I am having trouble using org-agenda with org-journal.

Essentially invoking org-agenda and trying to list all todos does not
work as intended. I have included the debug trace and associated
configuration below.

I think this happens because the org-agenda-get-day-entries returns no
results, since the file exists AND has scheduled and deadlined TODOs
in the week in question.

What is also wierd, is that I have another machine with the same
configuration, but this issue only occurs on a new machine that I am
trying to configure. I think this could be because the packages on the
old machine are not up to date.

Any help/suggestions are most welcome and appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (0 . 1) 2)
  org-in-archived-heading-p(nil nil)
  org-agenda-skip()
  org-agenda-get-deadlines()
  org-agenda-get-day-entries("/home/anant/journal/20220117.org" (1 17 2022) :deadline :scheduled :timestamp :sexp)
  apply(org-agenda-get-day-entries "/home/anant/journal/20220117.org" (1 17 2022) (:deadline :scheduled :timestamp :sexp))
  org-agenda-list(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda-list nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda-list)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x157424b3837d>)()
  funcall(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x157424b3837d>))
  (let nil (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x157424b3837d>)))
  eval((let nil (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x157424b3837d>))))
  org-agenda-run-series("Agenda and all TODOs" (((agenda "") (alltodo ""))))
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda record nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-agenda" "org-agenda")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-agenda" "org-agenda")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Here is my org-mode related configuration:

```
  (use-package org
    :straight t
    :config
    (org-babel-do-load-languages
    'org-babel-load-languages 
    '((python . t)
      (shell . t)
      ;; (sagemath . t)
      ))
    :init
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda () (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'org-babel-tangle
                   :append :local)))
    :custom
    (org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
    (org-format-latex-options '(:foreground default :background default :scale 4.0))
    (org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "soul" t)
                ("" "color" t)
                ("" "ulem" t)
                ("" "amssymb" t)
                ("" "amsmath" t)))
    ;; (org-babel-default-header-args (:session . "none")
    ;;               (:results . "replace")
    ;;               (:exports . "code")
    ;;               (:cache . "no")
    ;;               (:noweb . "no")
    ;;               (:hlines . "yes")
    ;;               (:tangle . "yes"))

    (org-babel-default-header-args:sage '((:session . t)
                      (:results . "output"))))

     (use-package org-projectile
       :straight t
       :demand
       :ensure t
       :bind (("C-c n p" . org-projectile-project-todo-completing-read)
          ("C-c c" . org-capture))
       :config
       (progn
     (require 'org-projectile)
     (org-projectile-per-project)
     (message "Setting up org-projectile")
     (setq org-projectile-per-project-filepath "project-todos.org")
     (setq org-agenda-files (append org-agenda-files ;; (org-projectile-todo-files)
                    '("~/.emacs.d/agenda.org")))))


   (use-package evil-org
     :straight t
     :ensure t
     :after org
     :hook (org-mode . (lambda () evil-org-mode))
     :config
     (require 'evil-org-agenda)
     (evil-org-agenda-set-keys))


   (defun lieut/org-start-presentation ()
     (interactive)
     (org-tree-slide-mode 1)
     (org-tree-slide-play-with-timer)
     (setq text-scale-mode-amount 3)
     (text-scale-mode 1))

   (defun lieut/org-end-presentation ()
     (interactive)
     (text-scale-mode 0)
     (org-tree-slide-mode 0))

   (use-package org-tree-slide
     :ensure t
     :straight t
     :after org
     :commands org-tree-slide-mode
     :config
     ;; (evil-define-key 'normal org-tree-slide-mode-map
     ;;   (kbd "q") 'lieut/org-end-presentation
     ;;   (kbd "C-j") 'org-tree-slide-move-next-tree
     ;;   (kbd "C-k") 'org-tree-slide-move-previous-tree)
     (setq org-tree-slide-slide-in-effect nil
       org-tree-slide-activate-message "Presentation started."
       org-tree-slide-deactivate-message "Presentation ended."
       org-tree-slide-header t)
     :custom
     (org-image-actual-width nil))
```

PS: I am aware that there is another post:
[Can't view anything in org-agenda: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/cant-view-anything-in-org-agenda-wrong-number-of-arguments-0-0-2)
that has a similar issue, however the OP in the case submitted a one
line answer that does not help me at all in debugging this any
further, since I use vanilla GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1,
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.27, cairo version 1.17.4).

EDIT: I set `org-element-use-cache` to nil following the suggestion of @NickD , which does get rid of the error, however org-agenda now does not list any TODOs at all.

Unfortunately I cannot post all of the content in the journal file in question, but I created a test TODO entry as follows:

```
* Saturday, 22 January 2022
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CREATED:  20220122
  :END:
**  TODO Test
   SCHEDULED: <2022-01-22 Sat 12:00>
```

I tried to call org-agenda-get-date-entries manually to debug the
issue, and this seems to reproduce the error:
(Even though org-element-use-cache is set to nil)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (0 . 1) 2)
  org-in-archived-heading-p(nil nil)
  org-agenda-skip()
  org-agenda-get-deadlines()
  org-agenda-get-day-entries("/home/anant/journal/20220117.org" (1 22 2022))
```

Edit2: Forgot to add org-journal config

```
(use-package org-journal
    :straight t
    :defer t
    :init
    (setq org-journal-prefix-key "C-c j")
    :custom
    (org-journal-dir "~/journal")
    (org-journal-date-format "%A, %d %B %Y")
    (org-journal-file-format "%Y%m%d.org")
    (org-journal-enable-agenda-integration t)
    (org-journal-file-type `weekly)
    )
```

Comment: This *may* be a bug in the `org-element` caching code. Can you add `(setq org-element-use-cache nil)` to your init file, restart emacs and try again? If that resolves the issue, please consider submitting a bug report with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. If at all possible, consider including in your bug report, the agenda file that causes this: `/home/anant/journal/20220117.org`. OTOH, if that does not resolve the issue, at least you'll have eliminated one large swath of code that could have caused it and we can concentrate on the *other* large swath of code that remains :-)

Comment: Yes, you are right! setting that variable does get rid of the error. However the side effect is that org-agenda does not display any TODOs at all!

Comment: However, I was able to reproduce the same error again manually. I edited the post with this new info

Comment: Try with `emacs -q`: I cannot reproduce the problem with the above file and `emacs -q` (I had to `(require 'org-agenda)` to get `org-agenda-get-day-entries` defined). If that still fails, then post the Org mode version which you can get with `M-x org-version`.

Comment: Yes, emacs -q does get rid of the error.

Comment: However I could not figure out the source of the error. Keeping all org related configs commented does remove the error, but un-commenting any one of the use-package declarations for org, org-projectile or org-journal makes this error resurface.  PS: It seems that I forgot to add the org-journal config to the original post. I have edited the post above. Also, org-mode version is 9.4.4. Seems like it was built by straight.